# print compilation time of each file in visual studio C++

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

How can i create a table to get compilation time of each c++ file in visual studio 2005 project.

Answer (score 15):

I am using Visual Studio 2010 but other versions of Visual Studio may have something similar. In VS2010 you may add to the command line options /Bt+ which prints the time taken to compile each file. So in a project properties under "Configuration Properties" -> "C/C++" -> "Command Line" -> "Additional Options" add /Bt+

Setting the /Bt+ option results in the output (which is recorded in the log file) lines like the following:

```
time(c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\c1.dll)=0.05110s < 25394686804 - 25394831194 > BB [C:\not-important\nlopt-2.4.2\direct\DIRect.c]
```

More information on this option at
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2010/04/01/vc-tip-get-detailed-build-throughput-diagnostics-using-msbuild-compiler-and-linker/
which I found thanks to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513043/453436

There are plenty of ways to extract the time lines depending on what tools you have available to you. I did it under a bash shell with a combination of find, grep and perl. The following will give you the compilation time sorted with longest first.

```
find . -name '*.log' | xargs grep time | perl -ne '$_ =~ /=(.*?)s.*\[(.*)\]/; print "$1 $2\n";' |sort -rn
```

Comment: Thanks! I use VS2013 and this indeed shows compilation time per file. Using the "Build Timing" option as mentioned in another answer only shows compilation/link times per project.

Answer (score 3):

"Tools" -> "Options" -> "Projects and Solutions" -> "VC++ Project Settings"

Tick "Build Timing".

Comment: Seriously, it's that easy? I still like my solution! :)

Comment: Build Timing gives times for the various build processes, not for each file.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've used that version of the compiler, but I recall it prints the name of the file it's compiling to the console (when you use the command line build). If that's the case, then you can write a program that does the following:

1. CreateProcess on the command line compiler, redirecting stdout to a pipe
2. Read from the pipe, looking for source file names
3. Each time a source file name is seen, note the current timestamp
4. When the pipe is closed, print out the times taken for each file build

While this approach could be developed in C++, it would likely be easier to use a tool such as Perl to implement it.

Comment: wat about writing a Python script??

Comment: Sure, Python would be equally suitable for this.

Comment: could you give some lines of code to perform this????

hope i m not bothering you..